# ZoomControls on Google Maps API - how can I move it above a ButtonBar?

Tags: java, android

I have enabled the built in zoom controls in my google maps application, however, it shows on my footer button panel:

[image]

I want the zoom controls to be one top of the footer button bar.

```
public class MinuteMapActivity extends MapActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // the methods on the map are initialised here - onCreate
    zoomControls();
    satelliteDisplay();
    snapToMap();

}

// method for Zoomcontrols
private void zoomControls() {
    LinearLayout zoomControls = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);
    MapView zoomLayout = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.MapView);
    //zoomControls.addView(zoomLayout, new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    zoomLayout.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

XML Layout:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/MapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0zZsLcQS5Zeiqjbo1n8-nn2CqtxKIuTq2T6bskg"
    />

<!-- set zoom controls on map at the bottom -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

If I enable

```
//zoomControls.addView(zoomLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

it crashes.

Some assistance on how I can move the zoomcontrols above the bottom bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason it crashes is because you are trying to assign `LinearLayout` parameters to a layout inside a `RelativeLayout`, so you would have to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead.

Also, I am a bit confused as to why you are using a `LinearLayout` for your zoom controls instead of the pre-defined View called `ZoomControls`. Perhaps it would save you a bit of time?

If you want to place the zoom controls above your bottom view use

```
<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonbar" />
```

assuming you call your ButtonBar view `buttonbar`.

Comment: Ah, I was didn't know that there was a pre-defined View called ZoomControls. Let me try this out and i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

May you have missed the two line of code in your

```
            <com.google.android.maps.MapView.
```

so paste this two lines in it and you will got it. its working 100 percent.

```
              android:enabled="true"
              android:clickable="true"
```